# No puedo utilizar una funcion en Java

Tags: java, funciones, clase

estoy intentando crear un programa en java, bastante simple, pero no entiendo la manera de funcionamiento de las clases ni el instanciamiento, ni las funciones, estoy intentado crear un menu con switch case, que a su vez en cada caso llame a una funcion, la creo, y no funciona, me dice que la clase no esta instanciada, pero segun lo que busque no es una clase, asi que la cambie a forma clase, y sigue sin funcionar, este es el codigo

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
        Main prueba = new Main();
        System.out.println("Sistema de matrices.");
        System.out.println("Opcion 0: Matriz 4x4 diagonal principal.");
        System.out.println("Opcion 1: Matriz 4x4 con triangular inferior.");
        System.out.println("Opcion 2: Matriz 4x4 con triangular superior.");
        System.out.println("Opcion 4: Salir.");
        int i = lector.nextInt();
        while (i < 0 || i > 4) {
            System.out.println("Ingrese una opcion valida: ");
            i = lector.nextInt();
        }
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                prueba.graficador1();

        }
        System.out.println("1");


    }

    public void graficador1() {
        int m=0;
        int n=0;
        int[][] matrix1 = new int[m][n];
        for (m = 0; m < 3; m++) {
            for (n = 0; n < 3; n++) {
                if (m == n) {
                    matrix1[m][n] = 1;
                } else matrix1[m][n] = 0;
            }
        }
        System.out.print(matrix1);
    }
}
```

Se supone que la funcion graficador tiene forma de clase, pero sigue sin funcionar, alguna idea? O donde esta el error. (Es obligatorio que tenga forma de función.

Comment: Cuando el método o función está **en la misma clase**, no tienes que  instanciar la clase para llamarlo, pues ya estás en la clase. Así que esto sobra: `Main prueba = new Main();` y la llamada, en vez de `prueba.graficador1();` tiene que ser simplemente: **`graficador1();`**

Comment: Recibo este error si lo hago Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal Graficador
Causado por: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Graficador

Comment: ¿Dónde ocurre eso? Tu código actual no hace referencia a ninguna clase llamada `Graficador`

Comment: Por otra parte, si quieres usar ese método desde un contexto estático, deberás declararlo como estático: `public static void graficador1() {`

Comment: Ocurre cuando hago la modificacion que me mencionas en el primer comentario, queda asi, public static void graficador1() y lo llamo graficador1();, pero ocurre el error que mencione

Comment: Tu metodo funciono completamente, ahora quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de mostrar cada fila de la matriz en una linea distinta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Espero que ésta pequeña explicación sobre el código te sirva

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        // Main no necesita instanciarse a si mismo, por lo que
        // Main prueba = new Main(); debe ser eliminado
        
        // definimos lector como scanar
        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);

        // variable que recoge la opcion elegida, es importante que el nombre
        // de las variables indiquen cual es su función, por claridad
        int opcion;
        
        // variables para el tamaño de la matriz
        int fil, col;
        
        // entramos en el bucle del menú, del que sólo podremos salir pulsando 4
        do {
            System.out.println("Sistema de matrices.");
            System.out.println("Opcion 1: Matriz 4x4 diagonal principal.");
            System.out.println("Opcion 2: Matriz 4x4 con triangular inferior.");
            System.out.println("Opcion 3: Matriz 4x4 con triangular superior.");
            System.out.println("Opcion 4: Salir.");
            System.out.print("Opcion: ");
            
            opcion = lector.nextInt();

            switch (opcion) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Dimensiones de la matriz: ");
                    System.out.print("Número de Filas: ");
                    fil = lector.nextInt();
                    System.out.print("Número de Columnas: ");
                    col = lector.nextInt();
                
                    graficador1(fil, col);
                
                    break;
                        
                case 2:
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Sin programar\n");
                    break;
              
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("FIN DEL PROGRAMA\n");
                    break;
                
                default:
                    System.out.println("OPCION NO VALIDA\n");
                    break;      
            }
        } while (opcion != 4);
    }

    // Main es un método estatico, desde un método estatico
    // solo se puede llamar a otros métodos estaticos, por ello 
    // declaramos graficador1 como static
    // Recibe como parámetro las dimensiones de la matriz.
    // Si te fijas en tu código, tu matriz tenia como dimensiones 
    // 0 - 0, y tratabas de acceder a posiciones de la matriz que no exiastian
    public static void graficador1(int fil, int col) {
        
        // declaramos la matriz con las dimensiones que hemos pasado como parámetro
        int[][] matrix1 = new int[fil][col];
        
        // recorrido típico de una matriz
        for (int i = 0; i < fil; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                if (i == j)
                    matrix1[i][j] = 1;
                else 
                    matrix1[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
        
        // Las matrices no se puden imprimir con System.out.println(matrix1);
        // debe realizarse un recorrido de la misma e imprimir valor a valor.
        for (int i = 0; i < fil; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(matrix1[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();     
        }
    }
}
```